# Redshift: Multiple rows for same ID in table, discard older rows?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table `my_table` in RedShift as follows:

```
id, update_time, value
abc, 2019-10-01 05:05:05, 20
xyz, 2020-01-22 01:02:03, 40
abc, 2019-11-11 15:15:15, 40
jul, 2020-05-05 02:02:02, 55
```

The id `abc` has two rows, and I would like to keep only the rows with the latest `update_time` values in the table, deleting the rest. Using something like this:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo as 
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY update_time DESC) AS row_number FROM my_table
```

gives

```
id, update_time, value, row_number
abc, 2019-10-01 05:05:05, 20, 2
xyz, 2020-01-22 01:02:03, 40, 1
abc, 2019-11-11 15:15:15, 40, 1
jul, 2020-05-05 02:02:02, 55, 1
```

So now I'm able to identify the latest row as that with row_number of 1. How would I use this to delete the rows from the original table, i.e. from `my_table`? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery and `WHERE`:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo as 
    SELECT t.*
    FROM (SELECT t.*,
                 ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY update_time DESC) AS row_number
          FROM my_table t
         ) t
    WHERE row_number = 1;
```

EDIT:

For a `DELETE`, you can use `using`:

```
delete from my_table
    using (select t.id, max(t.update_time) as max_ut
          from my_table t
          group by t.id
         ) tt
    where my_table.id = tt.id and
          my_table.update_time < tt.max_ut;
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but I'm looking to delete the rows from the _original_ table, and not the temp one. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

alternative to Gordon's answer (which is much more natural way to do the things than what I suggest below) is to create some unique Id for a rows instead of your ids which are not unique within the table. So, I guess something like this should work

```sql
numbered as (
    select id + update_time id_1
        , row_number() over (partition by id order by update_time desc) as rn 
    from my_table
)
delete from my_table 
where id + update_time in (
    select id_1
    from numbered
    where rn > 1
)
```

But it can create collisions when id and datetime are the same in first row and a  few next rows, this case this query removes all the data within the collision (what is also the case for Gordon's answer but in part of NOT deletion such duplicates)

Thus you need to analyze your table for such collisions

```sql
select count(*) 
from (
    select id + update_time
        , row_number() over (partition by id + update_time) as rn 
    from my_table
) 
where rn > 1
```

if this query returns nothing then you're safe and can run delete query. Else you need to seed some other field into new id to make it unique, something like `id + update_time + value as id_1`